# Spawning prefabs in Command

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm new to making multiplayer game in unity. I'm trying to spawn a bullet prefab on a player my question is do I have to spawn my prefab even if it's a client bullet in the server using Command

```
[Command]
void InstantiateHook()
{
    bullet = Instantiate(bulletPrefab, this.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
    NetworkServer.Spawn(bullet );
}
```

or

can I just spawn it in player script with just a normal function

```
void InstantiateHook()
{
    bullet = Instantiate(bulletPrefab, this.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
    NetworkServer.Spawn(bullet );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Authority

It's important to understand authority in Unity Multiplayer. As a client, by default the only thing you have authority over is your local player to send commands with. Any authority must be given to the client through the server. The server is the god and has authority over everything by default.

## Network Identities

It's also important to understand how the server and client communicate. Each object (that is networked) has a network identity which identifies an object across the network. The primary number which identifies this object is an unsigned integer called the netID. This netID is a unique identifier that is consistent throughout all of the clients. For example, if we had Player A, Player B, and a Bullet, Player A may have a netID of 0 and this ID is consistent throughout every single client including the server. This way if I call a command from Player A to change a variable in my player, it knows I did this because of the netID.

## Networked Hierarchy

Now that we understand basic network synchronization and authority, we can understand the basic hierarchy of a networked game. Every single object that is networked is shared (same netID as stated before) by every client and the server. For example, if we wanted to spawn a bullet, we need the server to assign a netID to an object and distribute this bullet across all clients. Now we have a bullet game object with a consistent netID and it is perfectly synced because this object was instantiated on the server and client.

## How a Command works

When we call a command on our player object, remember this player object is on every single client and the server. So when we call a command, this function is no longer running on the client player object, it's running on the server player object. This is key because this is why we have such high authority.

## NetworkServer.Spawn

So in your case, we need to first call a command, this will give us authority and access to the server. After we do that, we need to call a function to instantiate a bullet, and UNet/Mirror should do this automatically via NetworkServer.Spawn.

So your code should look something like

```cs
//Somewhere in your player script

public GameObject bulletPrefab; //Assign this in the unity inspector as your bullet prefab

[Command]
private void CmdSpawnBullet() {
    GameObject myNewBullet = Instantiate(bulletPrefab); //Create a new bullet on the server

    //Now we have a bullet on the server, let's also spawn this on the clients to be synced

    NetworkServer.Spawn(myNewBullet); //A second parameter is optional, this is the network connection to assign authority to. In this case, the server would probably have authority since hacking would be rather easy if the client had authority over the bullets.
}

private void Update() {
    if (!isLocalPlayer) return; //Wouldn't want any other clients running this for your player

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
        CmdSpawnBullet(); //Spawn a bullet when we click our primary fire button
    }
}
```

This script will spawn a bullet on all clients. This bullet of course will do nothing, but that's for your own gameplay desires :)

Also a quick note I forgot to add. You **CANNOT** call a command from a object you don't have authority over. For example, if you were player A and there was a bullet which the server had authority over, then you can't call a command from this bullet since you don't have authority. Unless you add a **requiresAuthority=false** tag in the attribute.